# Question is closed as not clear even though I edited precisely

Tags: discussion, support, reopen-closed

I asked a question and people voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking". I have to admit I immediately saw why they were voting, so I made sure to add an edit with more information on the problem. I even edited twice and still no feedback from anyone.

Here is the question : [Python: How to push an entire folder tree to a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47295549/7692463)

Comment: Never use "give me *the best* solution" as question. If you already have a solution than explain what you want to improve, otherwise specify clear criteria for what you consider "better approach".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for your time, i edit both posts.

Comment: It is kinda of sad that this question is not getting reopened since i found an answer and I really think it could be useful to a lot of future users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand that the people who closed the question are not notified of your edit. Instead, it pushes your question into the Reopen queue for review.

The original question was unclear. While your edits solved that problem, your question is still somewhat broad, asking if it is possible to do a git push in Python. I'm not a Python guy, but it could also be a duplicate of [git push via GitPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836988/git-push-via-gitpython) now (which was the first result for "git push python" in Google), which seems to answer your rather broad question. If it's not, I would make sure you've covered your bases, as there are several [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions out there, so make sure you differentiate this.

Comment: Well as I said in my question, Gitpython is one of many solutions to my problem. I was trying to ask the community to help me find the best solution to it. Yes, I've made my research and did not find any question like mine. If it is, people need to vote for duplicate so I can find the answer.

Comment: Be careful, as off-site resource requests are off-topic as well. Asking for a library counts as that

Comment: I agree, though I don't think it applies in my case, because I know there is built-in ways of doing it. I'm just unable to get it working. Like using `subprocess`, but as the question is closed for no reason, I can't get any outside opinions. And if it is still unclear I get 0 insights on how I can help people understand. It is kind of odd.

Comment: I really thank you for your time though, I'll try to keep that in mind.

Comment: Keep in mind that asking for a "best solution" moves you very close to "opinion based" land since there will most likely be half as many "best" solutions as there are programmers who've done it ;)

Comment: I edited both posts.